# How to do the list css on the Nike Run Club page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I saw a beautiful page on the Nike Run Club page.

I especially like its CSS which layouts its List.

When on a PC, it displays like a Gallery, but when it's on mobile, it displays like a list.

**What I did:**

1. I tried to find out the css class on the event list(by using Chrome Inspector).
2. I found the class is called: events-group
3. I tried to find where this class is, but all css files referenced on that page are minified, so I do not know how to figure it out.

Here is the url:  [Nike Run Club](https://www.nike.com/events-registration/series?id=1480&days=0)

**Update**

Thanks to mkaminsky, I used that website to unminify those files and still cannot find where the events-group class is.

So I am thinking of doing it by using Bootstrap?

Comment: Why downvote and close? I am happy to learn, thanks

Comment: I have updated about what I have done so far.

Comment: You should learn to right-click and Inspect Element in Chrome (for example). Just learn all the tools that there are there, one by one. It will make your life easier. When done, start with "responsive CSS" search. The list is pretty trivial, although professionally executed job.

Comment: hi @AlexPakka thanks to reply. I did do that; otherwise I wouldn't know the class name, isn't it?

Comment: hi @AlexPakka also, if I didn't do it, I wouldn't know the referenced css files got minified. I thought everyone knows it. But anyway I have updated my post to explicitly point out what tool I have used to avoid further misunderstandings. Thank you.

Comment: A CSS beautifier can be found here: http://www.cleancss.com/css-beautify/ .  Will help restore the minified CSS to a nice readable format.

Comment: hi @ChristopherThomas thank you :) I have found the similar tools, but the problem now is there are too many css files(referenced or inserted from the js) and I don't know which one is the one I'm looking for.

Comment: There is no events-group class in css. Nor there is a need for one. `ul:{list-style:none}` is all that's required. To verify, reload the site in Chrome, Ctrl+Shift+F and search for events-group everywhere. JS-injected or not, Inspector will show all applicable CSS currently used. If anyone says otherwise, don't believe them ;-)

Comment: Agree with the above, doesn't matter where the styles come from really, the inspector shows all style rules applied to an element (at least in chrome and ff)  If you are pretty confident with CSS, that would likely be enough to work out how it's all done.

Comment: thanks @AlexPakka ChristopherThomas your comments shed light on it. I will try to figure out how the css works..

Answer (score 1):

**To Do It Yourself**

I personally like to use flexbox.

HTML

```
<div id="gallery">
    <div class="item">item 1</div>
    <div class="item">item 2</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#gallery{
  -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
} 

.item{
    width: 25%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { /*when less than 768px*/
    .item{
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

**To Look at What They Did**

There is one static CSS file (https://www.nike.com/events-registration/client-dist/styles/multi-main.min.css?v=1427736422699). You can load that into http://unminify.com/.

However, some other files are loaded.

```
if (window.nike && window.nike.exp && window.nike.exp.script && window.nike.exp.script.device_detect && window.nike.exp.script.device_detect.isMobile()) {
        // mobile
        nike.events.gadgetCss = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" media=\"screen\" href=\"" + nike.events.PROTOCOL + "//m.nike.com/" + nike.events.COUNTRY + "/" + nike.events.LANGUAGE_CODE + "/style.css?app=nikestore&version=latest&assets=skin_onenike,nike,nike.gadget.mobile.OneNikeFooter,nike.gadget.mobile.OneNikeNav,nike.style.nsg.nsg-mobile,nike.style.exp.exp-mobile,skin.onenike_mobile&assetType=STYLE\">";
        nike.events.gadgetJs = "<script src=\"" + nike.events.PROTOCOL + "//m.nike.com/" + nike.events.COUNTRY + "/" + nike.events.LANGUAGE_CODE + "/NikeScriptManager.js?app=nikestore&version=latest&assets=nike,nike.gadget.mobile.OneNikeFooter,nike.gadget.mobile.OneNikeNav,nike.geo.StoreConfiguration&assetType=SCRIPT\"><\/script>";
    } else {
        // desktop
        nike.events.gadgetCss = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" media=\"screen\" href=\"" + nike.events.PROTOCOL + "//" + nike.events.STORE_HOST + "/" + nike.events.COUNTRY + "/" + nike.events.LANGUAGE_CODE + "/style.css?app=nikestore&version=latest&assets=nike,nike.gadget.OneNikeNav,nike.gadget.OneNikeFooter,nike.style.nsg.nsg-desktop,nike.style.exp.exp-desktop&assetType=STYLE\">";
        nike.events.gadgetJs = "<script src=\"" + nike.events.PROTOCOL + "//" + nike.events.STORE_HOST + "/" + nike.events.COUNTRY + "/" + nike.events.LANGUAGE_CODE + "/NikeScriptManager.js?app=nikestore&version=latest&assets=nike,nike.fonts.Selector,nike.fonts.glyphPolyfill,nike.gadget.OneNikeNav,nike.gadget.OneNikeFooter,yepnope.injectCss&assetType=SCRIPT\"><\/script>";
    }
document.write(nike.events.gadgetCss);
document.write(nike.events.gadgetJs);
```

So you might also want to look into that.

Comment: Hi mkaminsky, thank you. I opened each one of them and searched the keyword "events-group", but none of them contains this key word. So I think maybe I can use the Grid system in bootstrap to do this job? Your css also works, but I just don't want to maintain the css by myself.

Comment: You could use Bootstrap. Bootstrap has a breakpoint set by default (you can see an overview at http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp). If you're looking for something lighter, check out http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/

Answer (score 0):

They have a breakpoint at 815px you can use media queries to have the columns to collapse at the breakpoint.

If you are using a framework like bootstrap or foundation that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Yep, that's what I am trying, with Bootstrap :)

Answer (score 0):

You can unminify CSS with [Online Minifiers](http://unminify.com/).

Here is the unminified version: http://pastebin.com/4dNYyET1

The steps I used:

1. view-source on the website
2. In the header, find the style sheet.
3. Open the style sheet, copy contents,
4. Paste contents into unminifier

Regarding the events-group class:s
The `events-group` class is COMPLETELY unused in the CSS or JS. It is simply a div used to group all three calender events.

I'm assuming you're trying to figure out how to make the entire events layout...

`inner-wrapper`: centers text vertically

`multi-card`: Builds/formats each card

`ul`: (events-group) don't show any bullet points

Here is the simplest form of what they did: http://jsfiddle.net/mfLaup65/

If you want it to be more inclusive, you could copy all of their CSS.

Personally, I think you should check out [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). It has many functions that do things similar. Nike's is extremely precise and there's a lot of css to do something quite simple.

Comment: hi Pachonk, thank you. I did exactly like what you posted here. and I explored 5 css + js files but cannot find the css class : events-group. I am thinking I may have to do it in other ways. Any good suggestions?

Comment: @Franva The `events-group` is COMPLETELY unused in the CSS or JS. It is simply a div used to group all three calender events.

Comment: Oh! I went the wrong direction!!! Then how to figure out what the css classes which are used for making that List/Grid?

Comment: Go into children and also parents.